# how to check variable type in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

i need to check a variable whether it is an integer or a decimal one.
if integer just have to showing the integer if is not show the decimal point up 2.
i just used the

```
toFixed(2)
```

but it will show the integer number also with two decimal points

```
<script>
function getDisco() {

  gross = "<?php echo $GROSS_NET ?>";
  dis = document.getElementById('Discount').value;

  document.form3.Discount.value = ((dis/100) * 100).toFixed(2) ;

 document.form3.dis_perc.value =  (((dis/gross) * 100)).toFixed(2) ;
 document.form3.net_tot.value = (gross - dis).toFixed(2);
 document.form3.gross.value = ((gross/100) * 100).toFixed(2);

}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see this as how to tell if a number is an integer but as a simple "how to format a number" question. Consider: `function formatNumber(n) {return n.toFixed(2).replace(/\.00/,'')}`.

Comment: @RobG Thanx it is a simple answer i got from, it's work

Comment: @RobG: happy to reopen if you want to edit the question a little to fit your answer (makes sense to me).

Comment: @FelixKling—up to the OP, happy to leave it as it is. ;-)

Comment: @RobG  I just change the line belove TO

Comment: document.form3.dis_perc.value =  (((dis/gross) * 100)).toFixed(2) ;

Comment: document.form3.disPHiddn.value = (( (dis/gross * 100 ) ).toFixed(2).replace(/\.00/,'') ) ;

Answer (score 0):

One simple way could be to use [**`parseInt`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function to obtain the integer value and check if it is the same as the original. If it is, then value is an integer, otherwise it is a decimal.

```
function func(value) {
    var integer = parseInt(value);
    if(integer === value) {
        // value is an integer
    } else {
        // value is a decimal
    }
}
```

```js
function showResult() {
  var num = document.getElementById("num").value;
  if(num) {
      func(num);
  }
}

function func(value) {
    var integer = parseInt(value);
    if(integer == value) {
        document.getElementById("result").value = integer;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").value = parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
    }
}
```

```html
<input id="num" type="text" placeholder="Enter number here">
<button onclick="showResult();">Show Result</button><br />
<p>Result</p><input id="result" type="text" readonly>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
isInteger = function(input) {
  if (typeof input === "number")
    return input % 1 === 0;
}
```

This will return whether the input is an int or not.

Test:

```
isInteger(1);      // true
isInteger(1.01);   // false
isInteger("2");    // false
isInteger("2.02"); // false
```

Comment: @RobG, updated answer.  If you're referring to the old answer, it would in the end return `false`, because `NaN % 1 === 0` is false.

Comment: Yeah, playing comment tag. ;-) Posted my answer as a comment since it's closed.